# How do HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE affects zsh directory history

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh per-directory-history plugin https://github.com/tymm/zsh-directory-history

I'm not clear that whether the history is limited by HISTSIZE or HISTFILESIZE

I do find some usage of HISTSIZE in the code, but I can hardly understand them.

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the difference between HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE?

`HISTSIZE`  is the number of cached commands. Once you reach that number of commands, the oldest commands will be discarded as new ones are saved.

`HISTFILESIZE` is the number of commands that can be stored in the history file.

Further Reading:

- [bash HISTSIZE vs. HISTFILESIZE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19454838/3536342), answer by [arturomp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583834/arturomp) which includes more details and examples.

Comment: With `HISTCONTROL="ignoredups"` involved, wouldn't they effectively become the same?